# My console is giving me an error?

Tags: c++

Hello there I was wondering if you may help me with my code the g++ console says "28    37  C:\Users\paul\Documents\C++\main.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'movie'"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()

{

int tomscore;
string movie;
int metascore;


cout << "Hello there what movie are you wondering about?" << endl;
cin >> movie;

cout << "What is the Rotten Tomato score of the movie in decimal form?"<< endl;
cin >> tomscore;

cout << "What is the metascore?" << endl;
cin >> metascore;

int average = tomscore+metascore;

int averageGOD = average/2;

cout << "The average score for" " " movie " " "was" averageGOD << endl;   
 }
```

Comment: Fix this line `
cout << "The average score for" " " movie " " "was" averageGOD << endl;`

Comment: `28 37` in the error message means that the error is on or near line 28, column 37,  that lets you know where to find and fix the problem

Answer (score 6):

This is an error:

> ```
> cout << "The average score for" " " movie " " "was" averageGOD << endl;
> ```

You need to use `<<` in between each item you are sending to the stream. Also it is redundant to put the spaces in their own literal:

```
cout << "The average score for " << movie << " was " << averageGOD << endl;
```

If you were trying to output quote marks then use `\"` within the string.

Comment: @EdHeal `<<` was required rather than `;` as the error message suggested

Comment: Perhaps he's really smart and is using the string literal "was" somewhere else, and doesn't want to create another string literal by making it " was "... True optimization skills. But maybe not.